# Error: tf.TensorShape(input_shape).as_list() (Following: keras.io/getting_started/intro_to_keras_for_engineers)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm a beginner in Python and Keras and I wanted to create my first CNN model.

By following keras.io/getting_started/intro_to_keras_for_engineers I want to build a model to predict cats and dogs based on the free "Kaggle Cats and Dogs Dataset" from microsoft.
Because keras supports images up to 256x256p I already resized the images to 200x200.

I use PyCharm with Python 3.11 because I did a Beginner Course with that IDE.
Also the line "from tensorflow.keras.layers import Normalization" is grey and "keras" and "Normalization" are red underlined. After installing both by the popup-window they still remain red underlined.
I would be greatful for every help!

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Normalization


# Create a dataset.
dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/kerasintroduction/PetImagesResized', batch_size=64)


normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
normalizer.adapt(dataset)

normalized_data = normalizer(dataset)
print("var: %.4f" % np.var(normalized_data))
print("mean: %.4f" % np.mean(normalized_data))
```

The output on console:

```
/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/kerasintroduction/venv/bin/python /Users/myname/PycharmProjects/kerasintroduction/Introduction.py 
Found 24946 files belonging to 2 classes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/kerasintroduction/Introduction.py", line 18, in <module>
    normalizer.adapt(dataset)
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/kerasintroduction/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/layers/preprocessing/normalization.py", line 287, in adapt
    super().adapt(data, batch_size=batch_size, steps=steps)
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/kerasintroduction/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_preprocessing_layer.py", line 258, in adapt
    self._adapt_function(iterator)
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/kerasintroduction/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/var/folders/cj/14zhyyln0hz807sc364yml180000gn/T/__autograph_generated_filegw0_px6e.py", line 10, in tf__adapt_step
    ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self)._adapt_maybe_build, (ag__.ld(data),), None, fscope)
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/kerasintroduction/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_preprocessing_layer.py", line 295, in _adapt_maybe_build
    self.build(data_shape)
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/kerasintroduction/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/layers/preprocessing/normalization.py", line 173, in build
    input_shape = tf.TensorShape(input_shape).as_list()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/kerasintroduction/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_preprocessing_layer.py", line 122, in adapt_step  *
        self._adapt_maybe_build(data)
    File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/kerasintroduction/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_preprocessing_layer.py", line 295, in _adapt_maybe_build  **
        self.build(data_shape)
    File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/kerasintroduction/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/layers/preprocessing/normalization.py", line 173, in build
        input_shape = tf.TensorShape(input_shape).as_list()

    ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I was expecting the values for colours of the image to be normalized into floating number between -1 and 1.